# How to get window decorations back?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, window-decoration

In 11.04, using traditional GNOME (**not** Unity), windows suddenly lose their decorations way too often:

[image: Gnome-terminal window with no decorations]

For the next time this happens, can anyone suggest a fix that would be quicker than logging out & back in (i.e., having to close all programs)? Perhaps relaunching some service or process?

**NB**: simply doing `metacity --replace` does *not* fully fix the GNOME session; at least  visual effects are lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `unity-window-decorator &` (or if you cannot type anything, go to a virtual terminal and do `DISPLAY=:0.0 unity-window-decorator &`).

Comment: Thanks! I try this the next time it happens. By the way, does `unity-window-decorator &` work even when I'm **not** using Unity (see question)?

Comment: Yes, that's what normal Compiz in GNOME uses in 11.04 (it's even part of Compiz, not Unity).

Comment: Jeez, this bug is pretty annoying. I've had to use this command 4 times today so far...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue **permanently** by entering CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) —if you don't have it do `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`—, going into the *Window Decorations* options, and changing the *Command* setting to `compiz-decorator`.

Backing out of this menu, then unchecking Window Decoration, allowing the desktop to reload, then checking Window Decoration and exiting out of CCSM.

After doing this, I can no longer reproduce the issue.