# Lost Windows Frames, how to get them back?

Tags: compiz, xfce

I am running XFCE on 12.04 on an ASUS 1201N netbook.

Since yesterday's (2013-03-31) update I have no more window borders so I can't move them, resize, close.

Also the keyboard shortcuts seem to be gone.

Any suggestions would be great!

(maybe it's an April fools joke? ;)

I looked at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46685/how-to-get-window-decorations-back) and following the instructions got the windows title bar back. Now I can close, minimize, or maximize but still can't move or resize.  Also, the windows seem to "blink" when I try the context menu.

Please someone help!   I am in a big programming task and this is blocking everything!

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Actually, the stuff in the compiz post doesn't work at all. I've had to revert to gnome, which works but is so much less efficient than XFCE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like xfwm4 is messed up..Try this `rm -R ~/.cache/sessions/*` and logout/login..

Comment: That did it!  You are a genius! Thanks so much. (I tried to "vote-up" your answer but I don't have a good enough reputation to vote...  Anyway, thanks so much! Ciao,Bob :-)

Comment: Not a problem. Anytime.

Comment: But now I've got a new XFCE problem. The windows are unresponsive to mouse or ALT key shortcuts, as if the CPU were overloaded?  I tried clearing the sessions cache, bu that did nothing? What could be wrong? Thanks for any thoughts!